# How to Fix NetSuite SuiteScript Not Executing on Invoice 'Paid In Full'

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I have a User Event After Submit SuiteScript 1.0 deployed to the Invoice, and I can't seem to get it to fire. I need it to run after the payment is made and the Invoice status gets updated to 'Paid In Full'(assuming the invoice being updated after payment is an after submit event?) It will run if I go back to the invoice and edit/save. Should this be running on a different event type?

```
function userEventAfterSubmit_populateAfter(type) {

var createdFromField = nlapiGetFieldValue('createdfrom');
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'SO Created From Invoice', createdFromField);

var invoiceStatus = nlapiGetFieldValue('status');
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Invoice Status =', invoiceStatus)


if ((createdFromField) && (invoiceStatus == 'Paid In Full')){

//DOES NOT MAKE IT HERE, UNLESS I GO BACK TO INVOICE & EDIT/SAVE...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that Invoice User Events are fired when the status changes to Paid in Full. You will likely need to deploy a User Event on the Payment record instead and determine whether the newly applied payment pays the Invoice in full.

Comment: Thank you! We have a 3rd party payment processor API, so I'm not sure how their payment process would impact this script, if at all. Also, thought the Invoice deployment was more appropriate to handle reversals with CREDIT/REFUND process.